# How do I optimize my Add/Attach calls for Entity Framework? (many-to-many insert)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

### What I'm trying to do:

I have a table of users and a table of bridges. The relationship between bridges and users is many-to-many. I am given a user and an IEnumerable of bridges, and I'm trying to add the user to each of the bridges in the IEnumerable.

### What I've Tried:

I've searched, but many posts are about `Context.SaveChanges()` being slow. For me, `Context.SaveChanges()` is fine. But I have `Add()` and `Attach()` calls in a loop, and the loop takes **37 seconds to run for n < 150** in debugging mode.

I've tried turning off `AutoDetectChangesEnabled`, but it appears I'm depending on that.

```
Context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
Context.USER.Add(user);
Context.USER.Attach(user);
foreach(BRIDGE bridge in bridges)
{
    Context.BRIDGE.Add(bridge);
    Context.BRIDGE.Attach(bridge);
    bridge.USER.Add(user);    
}

int result =  Context.SaveChanges();
Context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
return result;
```

### My Options (as I understand them):

- Redirect the user and do the operation asynchronously. (Avoiding because I'd like to give the user some feedback after it completes).
- Just make the user wait it out.
- Send the relevant info to a stored procedure and have the stored proc `SELECT` the bridges and do the `INSERT`. (Avoiding because my workplace will probably frown on it at best.)

### Question:

Is there any way to make the loop run faster, or am I stuck?

(I've only been working with Entity Framework for about 6 months, so the more explanation, the better.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you don't need to work with context in the loop, EF saves your entire object graph, instead you can do :

```
foreach(BRIDGE bridge in bridges)
{
    //Context.BRIDGE.Add(bridge); remove this line
    //Context.BRIDGE.Attach(bridge); remove this line
    bridge.USER.Add(user);    
}

Context.BRIDGE.AddRange(bridges);    

Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. I was basing my code off of [this post](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/893609/CRUD-Many-to-Many-Entity-Framework) (Ctrl-F "Second case, data already exists in tables..."), but in this case it works without the addition/attachment.